# Deploy - how can I efficiently deploy different exe based on parameters sent from web browser?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, deployment, clickonce

I have a webpage that offers an installer which adds an registry into user's computer based on the clients that the user has access to.

The installer is quite simple. It reads from its app.config, gets the client key and downloads configuration file that is used to create the registry.

Here is the thing, I use ClickOnce to deploy the app. The main logic of the installer remains the same, the only different thing is the app.config key. If the user has 5 clients, I have to publish 5 times since I separate different installers by setting different publish/install urls like below. BTW, I will have to define different Assembly Name too:
[image]

It's definitely not a good solution.
Is there any better ways that I can configure the installer to accept this parameter from the webpage, or other better ways to automate this process and then reduce the publish times?

Looking forward to any suggestions!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I finally done is to write a powershell script, modify related parameters in csproj and deploy them. But I failed to copy those deployed files to remote server(aws). If anyone has any experience on that, you're more than welcome to share your thoughts!